# How to detect transparent area in image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

i research about merge many image into a image in iphone. But i have some problem   about that. I want to detect transparent areas, which has a white background. I think it's possible to get a CGRect rectangle around the area during this and after i will drag my image into transparent area, but I do not know how I can identify it. So if i detected all transparent area in this image, i will have a CGRect Array.

You can see my image:

[image: nhay.net/CES.jpg]

Please help me, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

In terms of detecting transparent pixels, you can access the pixel buffer as described in [Technical Q&A QA1509](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1509/_index.html) and then iterate through the pixel buffer looking for pixels with an `alpha` channel value of less than 1.0.

But to extrapolate from that to the programmatic building an array of `CGRect` corresponding to contiguous transparent pixels is non-trivial. If you make simplifying assumptions about the nature of the transparent regions (e.g. circular), it's quite a tractable little problem, though your thin rounded rectangle that intersects many of the circles complicates the problem.

If your image with transparent areas is predefined, though, I'd probably just define them manually rather than determining it programmatically.

Comment: Thank Rob! However in my case, i have many image that needed detect. So when i detect it manually, i think it will lost many time. This is application you can see how to merge image to transparent in other image. https://itunes.apple.com/app/casetagram/id577363344?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

Comment: @LoiTruong Fine, then do it programmatically. It's not that bad. I'd suggest that you first master the pixel buffer retrieval and detection of transparent pixels, and then only tackle the `CGRect` detection algorithm once you're comfortable with those basics.